# For/while loop with an f-string

Tags: lua

How do I correctly perform a for-loop that returns as a f-string (like in Python.)

For example,

```
for i=10, 1, -1 do
test = string.gsub('checkbox[val = "a"]','a', i)
return test
end
```

Returns

> checkbox[v10l = "10"]

However, I was expecting:

```
checkbox[val = "1"]
checkbox[val = "2"]
..
..
checkbox[val = "10"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm honestly not sure what are you trying to do here. Lua has no supports for f-strings and you're trying to return multiple times from function?

This is probably the closest to what you want:

```
for i=1, 10 do
    print(string.format('checkbox[val = "%d"]', i))
end
```

You're doing the following:

1. Running `for` loop from 10 to 1, in opposite direction of what you want.
2. Replacing all occurrences of string `a` in `checkbox[val = "a"]` with loop variable, giving you resulting string and assigning that to (global, which is not good) variable `test`.
3. Returning string you just got, thus exiting loop and function that contains loop.

If you're trying to pass multiple values from loop to the outside world, you can do one of the following:

1. Add them into table and return it:

```
local tab = {}
for i=1, 10 do
    tab[i] = string.format('checkbox[val = "%d"]', i)
end
return tab
```

2. Accept callback, so caller passes in a function to call on each value:

```
function example(cb)
    for i=1, 10 do
        cb(string.format('checkbox[val = "%d"]', i))
    end
end

example(print) -- Here, we pass `print` as a callback, but it's usually your own function
```

Choose whatever better suits your particular interface.

Comment: That works perfectly! I've just started so I'm learning as I go along. I have so many ideas of how to implement things just a lack of practice. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to return the values within the loop outside of it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with examples of how this can be done.